# Lazy collection madness

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I'm using JSF <s>controllers</s> beans where I get some lazy collections from an entity.

I open a `UserTransaction`, get all the lazy collections and commit the `UserTransaction`.

Here is the weird thing. When I go to the page, it gives a lazy initialization exception BUT when I debug it and check the collections in the debug screen (By selecting the collection and looking at it in the Variables section) it doesn't give an error and everything works!!!!

WHAT IS THIS MAGIC?

EDIT: I understand the debugger initializes the collection but if I manually do Hibernate.initialize(theCollection) method it gives me an error 'no active session'

EDIT 2 : I managed to fix it, now I have this question, why does this work :

```
this.completedObjectives = user.getCompletedObjectives();
this.unlockedEntitlements = user.getUnlockedEntitlements();
Hibernate.initialize(this.completedObjectives);
Hibernate.initialize(this.unlockedEntitlements);
```

But this does not:

```
Hibernate.initialize(user.getCompletedObjectives());
Hibernate.initialize(user.getUnlockedEntitlements());
this.completedObjectives = user.getCompletedObjectives();
this.unlockedEntitlements = user.getUnlockedEntitlements();
```

Comment: The debugger calls methods on the collection to let you inspect its contents, initializing it.

Comment: If I do Hibernate.initilize(thecollection); it gives me an 'no session' error

Comment: If you want to know why some code doesn't work, you must post the code, and the stack trace of the error you get. In any case, using the debugger to figure out whend something is lazily-initialized or not is not a good idea.

Comment: New questions in new topics please